# How to split day, hour, minute and second data in a huge Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split, bigdata

I'm new to Python and I'm working on a project for a Data Science class I'm taking. I have a big csv file (around 190 million lines, approx. 7GB of data) and I need, first, to do some data preparation.

Full disclaimer: data here is from this [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-adtracking-fraud-detection/overview).

A picture from Jupyter Notebook with headers follows. Although it reads `full_data.head()`, I'm using a 100,000-lines sample just to test code.
[image]

The most important column is `click_time`. The format is: `dd hh:mm:ss`. I want to split this in 4 different columns: day, hour, minute and second. I've reached a solution that works fine with this little file but it takes too long to run on 10% of real data, let alone on top 100% of real data (hasn't even been able to try that since just reading the full csv is a big problem right now).

Here it is:

```
# First I need to split the values
click = full_data['click_time']
del full_data['click_time']
click = click.str.replace(' ', ':')
click = click.str.split(':')

# Then I transform everything into integers. The last piece of code
# returns an array of lists, one for each line, and each list has 4
# elements. I couldn't figure out another way of making this conversion
click = click.apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))

# Now I transform everything into unidimensional arrays
day = np.zeros(len(click), dtype = 'uint8')
hour = np.zeros(len(click), dtype = 'uint8')
minute = np.zeros(len(click), dtype = 'uint8')
second = np.zeros(len(click), dtype = 'uint8')
for i in range(0, len(click)):
    day[i] = click[i][0]
    hour[i] = click[i][1]
    minute[i] = click[i][2]
    second[i] = click[i][3]
del click

# Transforming everything to a Pandas series
day = pd.Series(day, index = full_data.index, dtype = 'uint8')
hour = pd.Series(hour, index = full_data.index, dtype = 'uint8')
minute = pd.Series(minute, index = full_data.index, dtype = 'uint8')
second = pd.Series(second, index = full_data.index, dtype = 'uint8')

# Adding to data frame
full_data['day'] = day
del day
full_data['hour'] = hour
del hour
full_data['minute'] = minute
del minute
full_data['second'] = second
del second
```

The result is ok, it's what I want, but there has to be a faster way doing this:
[image]

Any ideas on how to improve this implementation? If one is interested in the dataset, this is from the test_sample.csv: https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-adtracking-fraud-detection/data

Thanks a lot in advance!!

---

**EDIT 1**: Following @COLDSPEED request, I provide the results of `full_data.head.to_dict()`:

```
  {'app': {0: 12, 1: 25, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 12},
  'channel': {0: 497, 1: 259, 2: 212, 3: 477, 4: 178},
  'click_time': {0: '07 09:30:38',
  1: '07 13:40:27',
  2: '07 18:05:24',
  3: '07 04:58:08',
  4: '09 09:00:09'},
  'device': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
  'ip': {0: 87540, 1: 105560, 2: 101424, 3: 94584, 4: 68413},
  'is_attributed': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
  'os': {0: 13, 1: 17, 2: 19, 3: 13, 4: 1}}
```

Comment: Please do `full_data.head().to_dict()` and post the data in your question, it is not easy to reproduce your example.

Comment: Just did it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to `timedelta` and extract components:

```
v = df.click_time.str.split()

df['days'] = v.str[0].astype(int)
df[['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']] = (
      pd.to_timedelta(v.str[-1]).dt.components.iloc[:, 1:4]
)
```

```
df
   app  channel   click_time  device      ip  is_attributed  os  days  hours  \
0   12      497  07 09:30:38       1   87540              0  13     7      9   
1   25      259  07 13:40:27       1  105560              0  17     7     13   
2   12      212  07 18:05:24       1  101424              0  19     7     18   
3   13      477  07 04:58:08       1   94584              0  13     7      4   
4   12      178  09 09:00:09       1   68413              0   1     9      9   

   minutes  seconds  
0       30       38  
1       40       27  
2        5       24  
3       58        8  
4        0        9
```

Comment: It worked! Although it took a little bit more time than I would like. It took around 5 minutes to run over 10% of full data (MacBook Pro i5, 8 GB of RAM). This is a very clean implementation, thanks a lot! The only modification I did was to specify the numerical type as `uint8`. It does make a difference regarding memory usage. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to first split by whitespace, then convert to `datetime` objects, then extract components directly.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'click_time': ['07 09:30:38', '07 13:40:27', '07 18:05:24',
                                  '07 04:58:08', '09 09:00:09', '09 01:22:13',
                                  '09 01:17:58', '07 10:01:53', '08 09:35:17',
                                  '08 12:35:26']})

df[['day', 'time']] = df['click_time'].str.split().apply(pd.Series)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['day'] = df['day'].astype(int)
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour
df['minute'] = df['datetime'].dt.minute
df['second'] = df['datetime'].dt.second

df = df.drop(['time', 'datetime'], 1)
```

**Result**

```
    click_time  day  hour  minute  second
0  07 09:30:38    7     9      30      38
1  07 13:40:27    7    13      40      27
2  07 18:05:24    7    18       5      24
3  07 04:58:08    7     4      58       8
4  09 09:00:09    9     9       0       9
5  09 01:22:13    9     1      22      13
6  09 01:17:58    9     1      17      58
7  07 10:01:53    7    10       1      53
8  08 09:35:17    8     9      35      17
9  08 12:35:26    8    12      35      26
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!